# Number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progression, pattern-matching

I was wondering about sets that do not contain any $3$-term AP, and came to know that the official name of such a set is [Salem–Spencer set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem%E2%80%93Spencer_set). I was considering the question of counting the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$ for a given $n$. This is listed in [OEIS A051013](https://oeis.org/A051013).

However, neither on OEIS, nor on anywhere else could I find any literature dealing with the specific question at hand. So, my question is whether anyone knows of any formula (recursive or otherwise) for the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$ for a given $n$.

I tried my hand at a recursion technique and tried to use the fact that such a set either ends with $n$ or it doesn't. So, we have
$$T(n)=T(n-1) + S(n)$$
where $T(n)$ is the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$ and $S(n)$ is the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$ containing $n$.

These $S(n)$'s are listed in [OEIS A334893](https://oeis.org/A334893) (with the specific cases listed in [OEIS A334892](https://oeis.org/A334892)) but there's no formula for these to be seen.

Even if an exact result is not available, I would like to know whether it is possible to get any asymptotic results or even any useful bounds$^{*}$. Even references which may be helpful are welcome.

$[^*]$ A set that avoids a $3$-AP is also a set that avoids three consecutive numbers, which is known to be the Tribonacci numbers. So, the term *useful bounds* is to be read as bounds better than this.

Also posted on [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4865555/943723)

Comment: let $r_3(N)$ denote the maximal cardinality of a salem-spencer subset of $\{1,\dots,N\}$. clearly $2^{r_3(N)}$ is a lower bound for your question. meanwhile, by container method shenanigans, I believe it is known that $C_\epsilon 2^{(1+\epsilon)r_3(N)}$ is an upper bound.

Comment: @ZachHunter can you please share the reference in which you found the upper bounds...

Answer (score 3):

Fix a smallish integer $m$, and assume for simplicity that $n$ is a multiple of $m$. Break $\{1,\dots,n\}$ into $n/m$ consecutive intervals of $m$ consecutive integers each. Each such interval must itself be a Salem–Spencer set. So if we let $f(m)$ be the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,\dots,m\}$, the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ will be at most $f(m)^{n/m} = \bigl( f(m)^{1/m} \bigr)^n$.

The first $40$ values of $f(m)$ are listed in the [OEIS sequence entry](https://oeis.org/A051013), and $f(m)^{1/m}$ is observed to decrease. Even taking $m=7$ yields the bound $\bigl( f(7)^{1/7} \bigr)^n = \bigl( 65^{1/7} \bigr)^n \approx 1.81546^n$, which is already better than the tribonacci bound. Taking $m=40$ (the last entry listed) yields the upper bound
$$
\bigl( f(40)^{1/40} \bigr)^n = \bigl( 27{,}893{,}419^{1/40} \bigr)^n \approx 1.5351^n
$$
for the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ (at least when $n$ is a multiple of $40$, but making this more general will lose only a constant factor in front of the exponential bound).

Comment: Nice observation (+1)!

Comment: Btw, since you wrote that $f(m)^{1/m}$ _is observed to decrease_, the reason is as you yourself pointed out, $f(n)\le f(m)^{n/m}\implies f(n)^{1/n}\le f(m)^{1/m}$

Comment: Also, in [the table of entries provided by OEIS](https://oeis.org/A051013/b051013.txt), we get that $f(80)=3954433860697$ so that $f(80)^{1/80}=1.437022453191589$

Comment: $f(n)^{1/n}$ goes to 1 by Roth theorem

Comment: @FedorPetrov how are you using Roth's Theorem to predict that?

Comment: @SayanDutta The given argument shows only that $f(n)^{1/n} \le f(m)^{1/m}$ when $n$ is a multiple of $m$.

Comment: The size of any such set is $o(n)$, thus the number of such sets is $\sum_{k=0}^{o(n)}{n\choose k}=e^{o(n)}$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard you're right, I missed this point. I still have another idea to prove $f(n)^{1/n}$ is decreasing. Let me see if I can work the details out...

Answer (score 2):

Let $r_3(N)$ denote the maximum cardinality of a $3$-AP subset of $\{1,\dots,N\}$. It clear that $T(N)\ge 2^{r_3(N)}$.

Meanwhile, it was proved by Balogh, Liu, and Sharifzadeh that we have $T(N) \le 2^{C r_3(N)}$ for some constant $C$ [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03172). The proof uses the hypergraph container method; it is my understanding is that when there are extremal constructions that "outperform the deletion method" (i.e., beat the naive probabilistic construction), then such a result should always hold.

Originally, I thought that the '$C$' could be taken to be '$1+\epsilon$', but apparently this is too optimistic for various related counting problems (I thank Rajko Nenadov for explaining this to me).

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1)!